# Non-commutativity of the group ring of a non-commutative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $R$ be a unital ring. Let's define $R\left( G \right)$ to be the group ring of $G$ over $R$ with underlying set $\left\{ f:G\to R\left| {{\forall }^{\infty }}x :f\left( x \right)=0 \right. \right\}$. Then $R\left( G \right)$ is a ring with identity element.

I'm struggling to prove that if $G$ is a noncommutative group then $R\left( G \right)$ is a noncommutative ring (even if $R$ is a commutative ring).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By $\forall^\infty$ do you mean "all but finitely many"? I suppose you're talking about the group ring? Otherwise I don't know what multiplication on $R(G)$ you're talking about. And R should be a commutative ring? What have you tried?

Comment: For instance, ${{\forall }^{\infty }}\left( x\in A\to P\left( x \right) \right)$ is meant to represent: ${{A}_{T}}=\left\{ \left. x\in A \right|P\left( x \right) \right\}$, ${{A}_{F}}=\left\{ \left. x\in A \right|\neg P\left( x \right) \right\}$, $A={{A}_{T}}\bigcup {{A}_{F}}$, $\left| {{A}_{F}} \right|<{{\aleph }_{0}}$.
Yes, the group ring $R\left( G \right)$ is non-commutative if $G$ is a non-commutative group (even if the ring $R$ itself is a commutative one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $R$ is a non-trivial ring (ie $0\neq 1$).

Take two non-commuting elements $u,v\in G$ (with $uv\neq vu$). Then define $f,g:G\to R$ to be the characteristic functions of $u$ and $v$ respectively. Technically: $f(x):=\delta_{ux}$ and $ g(x):=\delta_{vx}$.

Then $$(f\cdot g)(uv)=\sum\limits_{xy=uv}f(x)g(y)=f(u)g(v)=1$$
but
$$ (g\cdot f)(uv)=\sum\limits_{xy=uv}g(x)f(y)=0$$
because $f(x)\cdot g(y)=1$ if and only if $x=v$ and $y=u$, but $vu\neq uv$ by our initial assumption.